# IE gives "ERROR" and "Permission denied" for AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete, jsonp

I have this script which is making AJAX call (JSONP)

```
  $("#searchbox").autocomplete({ 


      source: function(request, response) {

        $.ajax({

          url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql',

          dataType: 'JSONP',

          data: {

            format: 'json',

            q: 'select * from xml where url="http://google.com/complete/search?hl=nl&output=toolbar&q=' + encodeURIComponent(request.term) + '"'

          },

          success: function(data) {

          if (typeof data == 'string') data = $.parseJSON(data);

              response($.map(data.query.results.toplevel.CompleteSuggestion, function(item) {

              return { label: item.suggestion.data, value: item.suggestion.data };

            }));

          }

        });

     },

       select: function(e, ui){


    },

   open: function(){
             doSearch($('.ui-autocomplete li:first-child a').text(), true, false);
             $(".ui-autocomplete :first-child a").addClass("ui-state-hover");
                $("#searchbox").focus();
             return false;


   },

    select: function(e, ui){
        $("#searchbox").autocomplete('search', ui.item.value);


    },

    close : function (event, ui) {
         val = $("#searchbox").val();
         $("#searchbox").autocomplete( "search", val ); 
    }



    });
```

I have Googled for it and it turns out its a security problem. Because the reqeust(output) is from an other domain (which is Bing). I have tried many things but with no luck.
This is my doctype and so on:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link href="desktop.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asap' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link class="jsbin" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
 <script src="livesearch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Loved+by+the+King' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    </head>
```

From her on there is nothing else but plain HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Unless this service does support `jsonp` you should do this:

1. Make a ajax-call to a php-file on your server.
2. In you php-file you use cURL with the original `jsonp`-statement you posted in your first post
3. Format your results from the query and output it so the javascript can access it
4. Done!

Comment: That seems like a detour. I was hoping for something more direct (and simple..) For the record; it works fine in all other browsers

Comment: Unless the site you try to access support `jsonp` and this is even possible (looks like it is not), cURL is the only way.

Comment: IE is stricker and more difficult to program with, hence this method is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

XMLHttpRequests are not allowed to make cross-domain requests due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) employed by web browsers. Use `JSONP` instead.

Comment: I think its a typical 'IE must die' problem:)